# Creating DNS Zone before projects relocation when using same NS records (No Downtime Allowed)

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, domain-name, ns-record

We have 2 accounts (servers), every account has different domains attached and because it's the same company all the domains uses the same nameservers. So according to this great response of @wesley https://serverfault.com/a/744148/462018

> The first person to have a zone on, for instance Digital Ocean, will be the one that controls it. You cannot have multiple identical zones on the same DNS infrastructure. So for example, using the silly names above, if I have wesleyisaderp.com as a zone on Digital Ocean, no one else on Digital Ocean's DNS infrastructure can add it to their account.

I can't setup the zone on my new account.

I would have liked to simply write a comment in the answer. But I don't have reputation.

So it's possible to create a domain zone in my second account with all the dns records and then just somehow switch to it? how to do that?
How to just change the account with out downtime?

Comment: You should contact Digital Ocean, not us. They can help you with this.

Comment: It's another company but, do you really think they can help with this?

Comment: If it is a different company, why does your question mention Digital Ocean? Anyway, you need to contact your service provider, whoever they are.